# How to update Xcode if not installed from app store

Tags: xcode, xcode11.3, xcode11.4

I’ve installed Xcode 11.3 from a zip file not from the app store and now Xcode 11.4 is here and I need it to work with ios 13.4 so how can I update it without downloading the whole Xcode again from apple downloads?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what the question here is. The normal way you upgrade Xcode via direct download is to download the new version, extract it from the XIP, and drag it into Applications. Are you having a problem with that? There is no patch-in-place; you just download the new version. It's generally a few GB.

Comment: it's more than 7 GB that's the problem  I was just looking for a better way to do so without having to download the whole Xcode again (the internet here- in Egypt- is awful )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to download the xcode again just 
Download 13.4 & mount from below link

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

Open to see its content and copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.4 to same path into Xcode application directory.

Restart Xcode

https://i.stack.imgur.com/onylj.png

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem.. but can I update the Xcode itself in the same way without having to download the whole Xcode 11.4 file ??

Comment: No appstore shows in update section but still download everything.

Comment: Do you know if the device/support files for 13.4 will run on Xcode 10.1?

Comment: my device have 13.3.1 and its working fine for xcode 10.1 . So, i think it will also work fine for 13.4.

Comment: This is so helpful!

Comment: It should be made clear that this approach does not update Xcode in any way. This is a hack to add support for newer iOS devices on older versions of Xcode. This type of solution should be avoided since it does not improve Xcode and it does not provide support for newer APIs.